# $geoNear with Query doesn't appear to respect query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So assuming the following data in as a MongoDB document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(8), 
    "shopId" : "1", 
    "name" : "SomeProduct", 
    "price" : "0.00", 
    "image" : "someUrl", 
    "description" : null,  
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -0.7572565, 
            52.0726237
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run the following aggregate:

```
collection.aggregate(
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [position.long, position.lat] },
                    maxDistance: 5 * 1609.34,
                    distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
                    key: "location",
                    query: { name: /foo/ },
                    spherical: true,
                },
            },
            ).toArray())
```

I still get back the document associated with SomeProduct, but it obviously should match a query that requires the name to have "Foo"?

Also, I don't seem to get the distance field included in the results? I'm reasonably new to MongoDB so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've actually figured this out, I'll post an answer shortly if anyone can spot the silly little syntax "mistake" feel free to answer and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: `query` should have been `query: { name: "foo" }`?

Comment: have you created the index for the field?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your suggestions please see my answer below, silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my workflow resulted in this issue, originally I'd tried collection.find({....}) now when I started reading about $geoNear I just swapped out find for collection.aggregate({....}) - the problem is aggregate needs an array of objects not just one object

Working code(note the addition of []), also when I switched to a variable for search string I needed to create the regex up front and then use $regex.:

```
let searchRegex = new RegExp(searchString)

collection.aggregate(
            [{
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [position.long, position.lat] },
                    maxDistance: (radius * 1609.34),
                    distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
                    query: { name: { $regex: searchRegex } },
                    key: 'location',
                    spherical: true,
                },
            }],
            ).toArray())
```